# Append lists in F# one-liner

Tags: list, f#

I'm trying to implement a RLE decoder for a game, and it works, but I'd like to shrink the code a bit, but I can't figure out how to put `List.append` and the `repeat` and `rleExpand` calls on one line

The signature of List.append is `List.append : 'T list -> 'T list -> 'T list`, so obviously I cannot just do 
`List.append(repeat(pattern,count), rleExpand(tail,rleTag))` - but would like to know how to do that. I also can use the @ operator - maybe that's the most readable one. But how do I use List.append if my lists are created by a function application like in the listing below?

```
let rec repeat(item,count) = 
    match count with 
    | 0 -> []
    | n -> item :: repeat(item,n-1) 

let rec rleExpand(packed, rleTag: int) =
    match packed with
    | [] -> []    
    | tag :: count :: pattern :: tail when tag = rleTag ->
        let repeated = repeat(pattern,count)
        let rest = rleExpand(tail,rleTag)
        List.append repeated rest
    | head :: tail -> head :: rleExpand(tail,rleTag)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably write:

```
repeat(pattern,count) @ rleExpand(tail,rleTag)
```

But you can also write

```
List.append (repeat(pattern,count)) (rleExpand(tail,rleTag))
```

You cannot use `List.append(repeat(pattern,count), rleExpand(tail,rleTag))` as you originally suggested because `List.append` takes curried (rather than tupled) arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this work?

```
let repeat(item, count) = [for i in 1 .. count -> item]

let rec rleExpand(packed, rleTag: int) =
    match packed with
    | [] -> []    
    | tag :: count :: pattern :: tail when tag = rleTag ->
        List.collect id [repeat(pattern,count);  rleExpand(tail,rleTag)]
    | head :: tail -> head :: rleExpand(tail,rleTag)
```

It's also more commonplace to use make functions curryable by not using tuples as parameters.

Comment: For repeat it is better to write `let repeat (item, count) = List.init count (fun _ -> item)`. It is likely to be faster.

Comment: Looks like you're right.  I just did a quick test with `count = 1000000` and `List.init` is indeed a bit faster than the comprehension.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions for a nicer repeat function :)